# This List Overlap program is giving weird outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was doing an exercise in which we make two lists and then we have to create a programme that would return a list that contains only the elements that are common between the lists.

I wrote the code as -

```
print('Please type in your list number 1')
list_1=input() 

print('Great! Please type in your list number 2 ')
list_2=input()

commonlist=[] # this will be the list containing common elements.


for i in range(len(list_1)):
    if list_1[i] in list_2:
        commonlist.append((list_1[i])) # this will put the common elements between the two lists in commonlist

print(commonlist)
```

Now, if my `list_1` is `[1,2,3,4,5]` and my `list _2` is `[3,4,5,6,7,8,9`] then the  expected output should be

> [3,4,5]

But the output is

> [‘[', ',', ',', '3', ',', '4', ',', '5', ']']

Why am I getting this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I'll try to explain it as simple as possible.

Your `input()` gets anything given to it as a `string`. And you need to typecast to what you need.

Try this in your python interpreter.

```
>>> a=input()
5
>>> a+10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    a+10
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Why the error is thrown. This is called as **strongly typed language**. Meaning python doesn't allow this you need to change it into your desired type to get what you want. Try this?

```
>>> a=input()
5
>>> int(a)+10
15
>>>
```

Now it works because we added a `int()` this is typecasting. Now in your problem you are just getting them as strings and using them.

With that said you have to change them into list using `list(input())` Even then those unwanted whitespaces from your string comes.

```
>>> a
'1 2 3 4'
>>> list(a)
['1', ' ', '2', ' ', '3', ' ', '4']
```

In this case use split(). By default `your_string.split()` returns a list split by whitespaces. You can even specify on what delimiter to split. So here no need to use `list()`

```
>>> a
'1 2 3 4'
>>> a.split()
['1', '2', '3', '4']

print('Please type in your list number 1')
list_1=input().split() 
print(list_1)
print('Great! Please type in your list number 2 ')
list_2=input().split()
print(list_2)
commonlist=[] # this will be the list containing common elements.


for i in range(len(list_1)):
    if list_1[i] in list_2:
        commonlist.append((list_1[i])) # this will put the common elements between the two lists in commonlist

print(commonlist)
```

output:

```
Please type in your list number 1
1 2 3 4
['1', '2', '3', '4']
Great! Please type in your list number 2 
2 3 5 6
['2', '3', '5', '6']
['2', '3']
```

See you got what you wanted although i would suggest this way to find common elements in list. Far simpler.

```
print('Please type in your list number 1')
list_1=input().split() 

print('Great! Please type in your list number 2 ')
list_2=input().split() 

commonlist = set(list_1)&set(list_2)


print(list(commonlist))
```

**commonlist = set(list_1)&set(list_2)** ends in one line. Do it the python way. The easy way.

**NOTE**: This doesn't give the common items in a ordered way. But you'll get all the common ones.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your getting that weird output is because `input()` returns a string. So you are iterating over strings not lists.

You can fix this by using `str.split()` to create a list of values from the input:

```
print('Please type in your list number 1')
list_1=input().split()

print('Great! Please type in your list number 2 ')
list_2=input().split()
```

Note your input will have to whitespace separated.

Also as a side note, if order does not matter, you can use `set()`s here instead:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [2, 6, 1, 8]
>>> 
>>> set(a) & set(b)
{1, 2}
>>>
```

Comment: Also, the original code works for python2.7 without changes

Comment: @VMRuiz that is a valid point. But I decided to omit that since it was pretty clear the OP was using Python3. And besides, using `input()` in Python2 is evil ;-)

Comment: Of course, it was just an addiction to your answer, not a complaint

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `input()` returns a `str` object. So when you iterate over a string, it is treated as a list of characters.

If you want to enter the list in the format you posted, you'll need to take it as a string and then *parse* it to get a list of integers. The `split()` method of the `str` class would be helpful. You'll need to specify a delimiter if needed.

Answer (score 1):

input() saves entered data as string.  You need to convert that input into a list.
You need to do some changes into program. It would look like this:

```
print('Please type in your list number 1(separated by ",") ')
list_1=input().split(",") 

print('Great! Please type in your list number 2(separated by",")')
list_2=input().split(",") 

commonlist=[] # this will be the list containing common elements.


for i in range(len(list_1)):
    if list_1[i] in list_2:
        commonlist.append((list_1[i])) # this will put the common elements between the two lists in commonlist

print(commonlist)
```

Please note that ththe list input should have "," between two numbers.
For ex:
23,45,67,54,67